# Truncated comment in inbox and can't see the rest of it?

Tags: support, comments, global-inbox

The following text appears in my inbox:

> 10 comments on Should we avoid using `<select>`?
>
> > @rybo111: I absolutely see your point - but also Spudley's. As you can see your question as a...

When I load the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101742/should-we-avoid-using-select) I cannot see the comment that is being truncated?

Comment: The comment has been deleted, but your inbox is still displayed a cached preview of it.

Comment: Ah, what I feared then. That's... infuriating. :(

Comment: Don't worry; you weren't missing anything terribly important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment has since been deleted.  It is still in your inbox due to caching.

There is no way for a non-moderator to see the deleted comment (in entirety).